# Test for Active Blackboard Session

Tags: single-sign-on, blackboard

We're using hosted Blackboard 9.1. I'm protecting some self-hosted course materials (HTML/Flash) with a coldfusion security wrapper. I'd like to bypass the security wrapper login prompt by detecting an active blackboard session.

Is it possible to do this with the cookies alone? Is there a Blackboard web service I can use, or do I need to have the Blackboard ICM team create a building block?

(I'm sure I will need to talk with Blackboard about this, but I want to go into the discussion sufficiently armed with answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session cookies are not set at the domain level, so I could not validate against them. The ICM team at Blackboard is currently writing a building block that will create a domain level cookie that I can validate against.